# Text doesn't get toggled back

Tags: jquery, text, toggle

I have this small toggle script, which toggles a panel, a class and text. I'm having trouble toggling the text though. It changes on the first click, but doesn't change back afterwards.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zXXUM/2/) is a fiddle. And here is the relevant code:

```
var visibleText = "Hide";
var hiddenText = "Show";
var textChange = $("#hidewrap a span");
var dynText = textChange.text() == visibleText ? hiddenText : visibleText;

textChange.text(dynText);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/zXXUM/6/) the answer.

Secondly, the explanation:
  Your logic to check the text of the `<span></span>` element was in $.ready method. jQuery invokes this method internally once per page load, therefor the logic would only check the text value of the span once. I simply moved the logic check `var dynText = textChange.text() == visibleText ? hiddenText : visibleText;` into the .click so that the check is carried out every time the link is clicked, as opposed to once per page load.

Comment: Thanks! Quite a simple solution. I suppose I didn't think quite logically.

Comment: @BramVanroy Cool, no problem, you had the answer. We all miss the small things sometimes. ;)

Answer (score 1):

[**working demo fiddle link here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rejRh/)

Visible text needs to become hidden and hidden should be updated with current visible text,

Shifting these 3 lines in bind event of click will do the trick for you:

```
   var visibleText = $("#hidewrap a span").text();

    var dynText = textChange.text() == visibleText ? hiddenText : visibleText;
    hiddenText = textChange.text();
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var panel = $("#topnav nav");
    var button = $("#hidewrap");
    var hiddenClass = "hidden";
    var visibleText = $("#hidewrap a span").text(); //"Hide";
    var hiddenText = "Show";
    var textChange = $("#hidewrap a span");


    var classAdd = $("aside#topnav");

    button.click(function(e) {
        var visibleText = $("#hidewrap a span").text();

        var dynText = textChange.text() == visibleText ? hiddenText : visibleText;
        hiddenText = textChange.text();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        textChange.text(dynText);
        classAdd.toggleClass(hiddenClass);
        panel.slideToggle("fast");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks. DeanL's solution a bit more to the point so I'll give him the credit. Thanks anyway (+1)

Comment: @BramVanroy No worries Glad it help in any case :)